# Mysql obtener todos los registros de tablas relacionadas de muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql

Tengo 3 tablas y necesito listar todas las opciones junto con todos los post que tienen o no tienen opciones, actualmente lo he realizado, pero me esta mostrando únicamente los post que tienen opciones pero los que no tienen opciones no me los muestra en el listado.

**El ejemplo en sqlfiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d27dd/1

Si se fijan en el listado, el post con ID 1, tiene 3 opciones que se le asignaron y me muestra una cuarta fila valor null, y el post con ID 2, tiene una opción asignada, pero necesito mostrar todas las otras filas con valores nulos de todas las opciones existentes en la tabla[post_options].

**Tablas:**

> **tabla[ post ]** - Guarda todos los post principales
>
> **tabla[ post_options]** - Guarda todas las opciones de los post
>
> **tabla[ post_has_options]** - Guarda todos los post que tienen opciones

**Código de las tablas:**

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_post_type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `create_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FK_title_UNIQUE` (`title`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_post_post_types` (`id_post_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('1', '1', 'Title 1', '2018-01-27 14:58:24', '2018-01-27 23:10:00');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('2', '1', 'Title 2', '2018-01-27 14:58:24', '2018-01-27 23:10:00');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('3', '1', 'Title 3', '2018-01-27 14:58:24', '2018-01-27 23:10:00');
INSERT INTO `post` VALUES ('4', '1', 'Title 4', '2018-01-27 14:58:24', '2018-01-27 23:10:00');

CREATE TABLE `post_has_options` (
  `id_post` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_post_work_type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `create_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_post`,`id_post_work_type`),
  KEY `id_post_work_type` (`id_post_work_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `post_has_options` VALUES ('1', '1', '2018-01-27 22:00:51', '2018-01-27 22:00:51');
INSERT INTO `post_has_options` VALUES ('1', '2', '2018-01-27 22:00:54', '2018-01-27 22:00:54');
INSERT INTO `post_has_options` VALUES ('1', '3', '2018-01-27 22:00:58', '2018-01-27 22:00:58');
INSERT INTO `post_has_options` VALUES ('2', '2', '2018-01-27 22:45:19', '2018-01-27 22:45:19');

CREATE TABLE `post_options` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `create_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FK_name_UNIQUE` (`name`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `post_options` VALUES ('1', 'Work type 1', '2018-01-27 14:59:30', '2018-01-27 14:59:30');
INSERT INTO `post_options` VALUES ('2', 'Work type 2', '2018-01-27 14:59:30', '2018-01-27 14:59:30');
INSERT INTO `post_options` VALUES ('3', 'Work type 3', '2018-01-27 14:59:30', '2018-01-27 14:59:30');
INSERT INTO `post_options` VALUES ('4', 'Work type 4', '2018-01-27 14:59:30', '2018-01-27 14:59:30');
```

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT *
FROM post_options P
LEFT JOIN post_has_options PHO ON PHO.id_post_work_type = P.id
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, lo que necesitas es hacer esto:

```
SELECT P.*,
       PO.*,
       PHO.*
       FROM post P 
       CROSS JOIN post_options PO
       LEFT JOIN post_has_options PHO
          ON PHO.id_post_work_type = PO.id
          AND PHO.Id_post = P.Id
       ORDER BY P.Id, PO.Id;
```

Mostramos cada `post` con cuatro filas por `post_options` mediante un `CROSS JOIN` o producto cartesiano, por último agregamos la información adicional de `post_has_options` (si existe) por cada `post.id` y `post_options.id`

**Resultado**:

```
| id | id_post_type |   title |            create_at |          modified_at | id |        name |            create_at |          modified_at | id_post | id_post_work_type |            create_at |          modified_at |
|----|--------------|---------|----------------------|----------------------|----|-------------|----------------------|----------------------|---------|-------------------|----------------------|----------------------|
|  1 |            1 | Title 1 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  1 | Work type 1 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |       1 |                 1 | 2018-01-27T22:00:51Z | 2018-01-27T22:00:51Z |
|  1 |            1 | Title 1 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  2 | Work type 2 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |       1 |                 2 | 2018-01-27T22:00:54Z | 2018-01-27T22:00:54Z |
|  1 |            1 | Title 1 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  3 | Work type 3 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |       1 |                 3 | 2018-01-27T22:00:58Z | 2018-01-27T22:00:58Z |
|  1 |            1 | Title 1 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  4 | Work type 4 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  2 |            1 | Title 2 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  1 | Work type 1 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  2 |            1 | Title 2 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  2 | Work type 2 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |       2 |                 2 | 2018-01-27T22:45:19Z | 2018-01-27T22:45:19Z |
|  2 |            1 | Title 2 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  3 | Work type 3 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  2 |            1 | Title 2 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  4 | Work type 4 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  3 |            1 | Title 3 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  1 | Work type 1 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  3 |            1 | Title 3 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  2 | Work type 2 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  3 |            1 | Title 3 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  3 | Work type 3 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  3 |            1 | Title 3 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  4 | Work type 4 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  4 |            1 | Title 4 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  1 | Work type 1 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  4 |            1 | Title 4 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  2 | Work type 2 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  4 |            1 | Title 4 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  3 | Work type 3 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
|  4 |            1 | Title 4 | 2018-01-27T14:58:24Z | 2018-01-27T23:10:00Z |  4 | Work type 4 | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z | 2018-01-27T14:59:30Z |  (null) |            (null) |               (null) |               (null) |
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ese era el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Con un left join puedes obtener todos los post que tengan o no tengan options, sin enbargo acá tocaría que usar dos left.

```
SELECT * FROM post AS p
LEFT JOIN post_has_options AS pho
    ON p.id = pho.id_post
LEFT JOIN post_options AS po
    ON pho.id_post_work_type = po.id
```

Intenta esa consulta.